# VSCode multiple/many tasks with keybinds

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to add more then 2 keybinds to more then 2 tasks. Like about 5-10.

Right now I have this:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    { "key": "ctrl+alt+s", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.test" },
    { "key": "ctrl+alt+d", "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build" }
]


{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "npm start",
            "isTestCommand": true,
            "args": ["start"]
        },
        {
            "taskName": "npm dist",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "args": ["run", "dist"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**How can you add more?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the updated version of vscode 1.10 you can now bind keys to any task. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_key-bindings-per-task) is the release doc describing this.
As per the example in the link you can do:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+h",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "tsc"
}
```

which binds ctrl+h to the task named tsc